# swapping 2 String values in jsf ui

Tags: jsp, jsf

So this is a pretty simple question and I just can't figure out why this isn't working as I expected.

My project is a unit converter in J2EE. HTML front end with Java behind.

I have 2 drop down boxes in my html page.

```
        <p:selectOneMenu id="convertFrom" value="#{conversions.convertFrom}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inches" itemValue="Inches" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feet" itemValue="Feet" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Centimeters" itemValue="Centimeters" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Meters" itemValue="Meters" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:selectOneMenu id="convertTo" value="#{conversions.convertTo}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inches" itemValue="Inches" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feet" itemValue="Feet" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Centimeters" itemValue="Centimeters" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Meters" itemValue="Meters" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

These drop down boxes are confirmed to work as I already have the conversion part done.

I am attempting to implement a "Switch Units" button so if you have Inches > Feet you can press a button and switch it to Feet > Inches. So convertFrom needs to be swapped with converTo.

```
public void switchUnits() {
    String unitTo = getConvertTo();
    String unitFrom = getConvertFrom();
    setConvertTo(unitFrom);
    setConvertFrom(unitTo);
}
```

I have a button on the html page which invokes this method (I confirmed it to work by hardcoding setConvertTo("Feet") and seeing it worked).

So through troubleshooting, I have determined the getter and setters are working correctly. And the button is invoking the method correctly.

So TLDR my question is what is wrong with the code in my switchUnits method? As written here when it's invoked nothing happens. Both values stay the same.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, please create a [mcve]. Cause might be in parts of the code not visible here.

Answer (score 0):

your question is Incomplete and parts of the code not visible here,you must write your  button code,but i think you need to update your selectOneMenus in button after invokes your method, like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="yourButton" action="#{yourBean.switchUnits}"
 update="form_id:convertFrom form_id:convertTo">
</p:commandButton>
```

id for selectOneMenus in Button update maybe change with your forms structure.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Soheil.St answer which states to update your components, I might add that you also need to put a `<p:ajax/>` inside `selectOneMenu` to submit its data partially.
without the submitted data, your choices are not reflected in your managed bean.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="convertFrom" value="#{conversions.convertFrom}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inches" itemValue="Inches" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feet" itemValue="Feet" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Centimeters" itemValue="Centimeters" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Meters" itemValue="Meters" />
    <p:ajax/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="convertTo" value="#{conversions.convertTo}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inches" itemValue="Inches" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feet" itemValue="Feet" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Centimeters" itemValue="Centimeters" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Meters" itemValue="Meters" />
    <p:ajax/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

you need to set `process` and address the `selectOneMenu` form in your button if its in another form.

Comment: I hope his button is in the same form with the selectOneMenus then.

Comment: Yes, but if not and the existing submit button is also not in the form, that default submission would also not work. So I assume (yes, bad, assumption I know) there is a form and at least the normal button is in there. Hence the request for a [mcve] and not guessing what might be the cause. Cheers and thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you mean by "default submission" but if you use <p:ajax/>  inside selectOneMenu to submit your selected value,it doesn't need a submit button at all, the selectOneMenu only needs to be inside a form, then if any of its option get selected, the setter of convertTo will be called and the value will be set in the backing bean

Comment: 'Default submit button' = the button to actually do the conversion. That **is** present simce the application is working, I quote _"These drop down boxes are confirmed to work as I already have the conversion part done."_